# Timeout if no user input for `x` seconds

Tags: ruby, timeout

How would I program a chunk of code in Ruby, which would timeout or exit if no user input is entered for `x` amount of time?

I don't have a half completed script too better convey my question, or even a pseudo-code concept algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Timeout](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html) module that is included in the standard libraries. It will raise a `Timeout::Error` on timeout if you want to `rescue` it.

```
require 'timeout'
x = 10
begin
  status = Timeout::timeout(x) {
    printf "Input: "
    gets
  }
  puts "Got: #{status}"
rescue Timeout::Error
  puts "Input timed out after #{x} seconds"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require "timeout"

Timeout.timeout(x) do
  s = gets
  ...
end
```